# Distributed indexing using lucene

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I have built a search application using Lucene in order to retrieve user details quickly. 
We have use cases where we index data according the request. 
More specifically:

- we fetch user details for specific requests and index them.
- subsequent searches for that user details are served through index.

We perform indexing instead of using  data directly from downstream services, because we need control on the user data that can be searched.

Additional requirements are:

1. We need to build a distributed index,  so subsequent requests for a given user refer to the same document (while at the moment we are building a doc for each local index) ;
2. We want to create index for each user and keep it for 30 mins(avg time a a user search is performed) and then remove/overwrite it.

Could you please help us with possible approaches to meet our requirements?

Comment: It looks like you want to keep lucene index for a user in it's session. How about persisting it like usual session data? Besides, how big is per user index and does the user details change with requests. If it is not too big and is static then u can just index it per request per machine. Will save you a lot of headache/resources synchronizing index across machines.

Comment: Any reason you are not using Solr with SolrCloud? You even tagged the question with Solr, so must be aware it would be a good match.